# Nesting setInterval in While loop

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to nest a setinterval loop inside of a while. The goal is to allow for a certain boolean variable to trigger the setinterval until another condition is true, then stop the iteration. Here is a portion of my code

```
while (checkTime) {
    const checkTime = () => {
        machineTime = new Date() - 0;
        console.log(machineTime);

        if (inputDate <= machineTime && inputDate != null && machineTime != null) {
            console.log("Match found");
            checkTime = false;
        }
    };
    setInterval(checkTime, 1000); 
}
```

I'm assuming this isn't the right way to what I'm trying to do. Can anyone give me a suggestion on a better way to achieve my goal? Thanks

Comment: Why is 'checktime' the condition for your while loop. You are using it before it is being defined. Also, you should use Date.now() instead of newDate()-0.

Comment: I just noticed that issue. Also, I'm using newDate()-0 to convert the date into a time stamp. Changing variable names didn't fix the issue of the loop not iterating despite variable being true

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe this is helpful to you: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ckwjm6gx/

Comment: @Matt 'Date.now()' returns a time stamp, and it is preferable to 'new Date()-0' because you avoid needlessly constructing a date object

Comment: Didn't know that! Still trying to active learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a while loop to do that. Just use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) to stop the loop once your condition is met.

```js
    let interval;

    const checkTime = () => {
        machineTime = new Date() - 0;
        console.log(machineTime);

        if (inputDate <= machineTime && inputDate != null && machineTime != null) {
            console.log("Match found");
            // This will stop the loop.
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    };

    interval = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

Comment: How would you re-start the interval? Calling setInterval again?

Comment: Just call `setInterval` again (last line of code above)